# Dynamically add click event to other forms

Tags: c#, events, button

I want to dynamically add a click event from form1 to form2.

This is my code in form1:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
string title =(string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
frm.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
//create button and it's event
Button button1 = new Button();
button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click);
button1.Location = new Point((myTabPage.Width/2)-(button1.Width/2),myTabPage.Height-30);
button1.Text = "Click On Me!";
myTabPage.Controls.Add(button1);
frm.Show();
```

I get the following error:
The name 'button1_Click' does not exist in the current context

Please help.

Comment: Have yo defined button1_Click any where on new form? If no, you must define it before binding it to any button click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your `button1_Click` event handler. At the moment you're assigning the event handler to the button saying "call button1_Click" but you haven't actually created the "button1_Click" method that you want to call.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   //code to call when the button is clicked.  
}
```

Update from comment. You can create an [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

```
button1.Click += (s,e) =>
     { 
         //code to call when the button is clicked. 
     };
```

Comment: yes i know it but i must add it into form2? it not working :(

Answer (score -1):

Could you create the button ahead of time and disable and make invisible until you wanted to use it?